# Form $_post, not display blank info

Tags: php, html, forms, post

im trying to make a form page, a comfirmation page and a add to database page, im having problems in the first two pages.

**form.php**

```
<html>
   <body>

<form action="ask.php" method="post">
name 1: <input type="text" name="name1"><br>
name 2: <input type="text" name="name2"><br>
name 3: <input type="text" name="name3"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

basically it ask for 3 names, and pass to ask.php but the problem starts if the user does not fill all the inputs. it displays name3 is (blank) if the user just fill with 2 names.
i dont what it to display anything related to name3 is name 3 was not filled

here is the code for ask.php

```
<html>
 <body>

 name 1 is <?php echo $_POST["name1"]; ?><br>
 name 2 is <?php echo $_POST["name2"]; ?><br>
 name 3 is <?php echo $_POST["name3"]; ?><br>

 </body>
 </html>
```

how to display only info that is filled? the problems is even biger if the form have more inputs

Comment: That's called logic, you can't get that from an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
if (!empty($_POST["name1"])) echo "name 1 is...
```

That checks if the POST-request value named "name1" is not empty and then proceeds with your output.

Comment: This will still show `name1` if it's blank. `empty()` might be a better check for what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <body>

 name 1 is <?php echo $_POST["name1"]; ?><br>
 name 2 is <?php echo $_POST["name2"]; ?><br>
 <?php if ($_POST['name3'] != ""): echo "name 3 is" . $_POST["name3"]; ?><br>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This should only display name3 if there is something inserted into the input. If it's a space or a character or whatever will display it regardless.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put some validations in the form to avoid user from remaining empty input field in the form? Use `required` property of `input` tag.

Use as following:

```
<html>
   <body>

<form action="ask.php" method="post">
name 1: <input type="text" name="name1" required><br>
name 2: <input type="text" name="name2" required><br>
name 3: <input type="text" name="name3" required><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

 </body>
</html>
```

The required specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

[more info about required proerty](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

hope this will help.

Comment: because they are not required. there are 3 fields in case someone need to enter extra info

Comment: ok...I did mistake in understanding.

Comment: dont worry, might be my mistake because of my bad english